# How to tell Google/Facebook fetch "#!" URLs with "_escape_fragment_"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, seo, hashtag

I have a AJAX-heavy web site and wanted to make it more search engine friendly. I read the following articles [1](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification),[2](http://blog.christoffer.me/post/2013-04-20-how-to-make-spa-websites-more-search-friendly/#.Vg_SyhrR_VQ)
and others, know that Google finds links with "#!" will convert into "_escaped_fragment_", so I wrote a javascript to create and store snapshot of pages dynamically.
 
for example:
The original page ( pretty URL )
http://54.254.240.142/#!/article?uid=Sample-daad6i1m7kacerk9&search=
will create a snapshot in the following link ( ugly URL )
http://54.254.240.142/_escaped_fragment_/article%3Fuid%3DSample-daad6i1m7kacerk9

However, Google can not fetch it, Facebook can't fetch it either. 
Umm I am not sure the format of URL mapping between pretty and ugly URLs. 
Any hints or tips would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I feel like clicking those scary looking links... Is there no way to make your question more self-contained? (If this question ever becomes famous, we'd like it to stay relevant, even if referenced websites go off-line...)

Comment: It's a little bit scary when traditional Chinese are encoded, however, in document 1 Google show me everything after "_escaped_fragment_" should be encodeURIComponent(), so I did it...
in the mean time, which link go off-line?

Comment: I edited the question, changed the links into English, hope this make the question look better. Thanks.

Comment: Your server needs to handle the second URL, and then serve an HTML document that contains the requested content. Also, at least according to Google, `_escaped_fragment_` has to be a query string parameter – whereas you have made it part of the path segment (and not even spelled it correctly.) And btw., when people say “pretty URLs”, they mean URLs that consist of something that is understandable to humans – your `/#!/article?uid=Sample-daad6i1m7kacerk9&search=` is certainly not “pretty” in that regard.

Comment: Thanks, problems solved, for those who having the same issue, specially NODEJS users, JUST DO NOT FOLLOW THE second tutorial article.